# How to allow windows services to the firewall settings of an SQL database from powershell?

Tags: powershell, azure, firewall

I'm trying to deploy services to Azure with a powershell script.  They will need access to an SQL database also created programmatically.

For external requests, you can specify firewall rules using:

`New-AzureSqlDatabaseServerFirewallRule -ServerName $serverName -StartIpAddress $startIP        -EndIpAddress $endIP -RuleName $ruleName`

In the portal, you can specify access from inside the network using

"Allowed Services: WINDOWS AZURE SERVICES" [Yes/No] (defaults to No)

How to set the last to "Yes" from powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use this command, it accomplishes the same mission. I would recommend using this just in case Azure changes the ip range that references Azure traffic.

```
New-AzureSqlDatabaseServerFirewallRule -ServerName $AzureSqlServer.ServerName.ToString() -AllowAllAzureServices
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `New-AzureSqlDatabaseServerFirewallRule` command with the StartIpAddress and EndIpAddress set to 0.0.0.0, the portal will interpret this as "allow windows azure services to access this SQL database."